# What does "government" mean in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, articles

The word "government" is a countable noun when it refers to the organization or the group of people that govern a country. But it can also be an uncountable noun when it means a form or system of government as in "The country returned to democratic government."

Now, here's a quote from a book.

> The combination of these two trends ... produces an incredible concentration of power in the hands of government and large corporations.

I would have expected to see "in the hands of government**s** and large corporations" or "in the hands of **the** government and large corporations. A definite article before "government" because in my understanding, the word "government" here refers to the political organization rather than the process of governing or some form of government.

What does the term "government" mean in the quote above? Does the lack of a definite article have something to do with the parallel structure (as in "between father and son")?

Comment: (1) You don't say, but is government or governments actually mandated in the article? Is it referring to one nation at one time? (2) If 'the government' is allowable here, 'government' is a close paraphrase, not emphasizing/connoting Mr Washinton and co (or whoever the key players involved at the time are) quite so forcibly.

Comment: I think "government" here is synonymous with "those who govern" or "those who run the government."

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks. So it's like "management" = "those who are in charge of a company."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The author is not referring to any specific country, and the "government" is used in a general sense. I ask, because it does not sit right with me when government, apparently used as an uncountable noun,  is used in parallel with "large corporations," which refers to multiple corporate entities in general.

Comment: I can understand the desire for more obvious parallelism. But I can also understand why someone would want to use the more amorphous non-count 'government'. There's sadly no non-count parallel for count 'companies'/'corporations'. Rephrase if you desire, but I wouldn't worry too much about the original.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Big business, perhaps?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, that certainly works grammatically. Perhaps though semantically, 'large corporations' is more incisive, less distancing.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "in the hands of government" has been used by authors such as Thomas Jefferson countless times since the 1700s.

For example [Letter to James Madison By Thomas Jefferson, December 20th, 1787](http://www.bartleby.com/library/prose/2875.html)

> Nor will any degree of power in the hands of government prevent insurrections.

"government" means "authority" or "legal authority"